# Objects become larger when Rendered

Tags: rendering

When I use render (as render region or render or render preview or actual render), objects become twice as big as I positioned them in front of camera (or camera comes twice closer..)

Here's the regular view through camera:

[image: regular view]

And here's render preview:

[image: render previw]

Does anyone have a clue? It's quite distracting.. Would be very glad for any help! Thanks!

Comment: make sure that you haven't keyframed the camera (select the camera, open the Dope Sheet, check if there's a yellow dot, delete it)

Comment: @moonboots no keyframes there

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/188aa2619d764add9621f19806e49d60 thanks for giving your attention to it!

Comment: There is another object "Sprinkle_medium" set as active camera, this is not a camera. This is the reason. Though, I don't know why it gives this effect. Select the actual camera then ctrl+numpad 0 to solve the issue

Comment: oh ok I think I get it, it must have to do with the default focal lens of an object that is chosen as camera, it seems like  it will be 35mm, and it looks like when you switch back to Solid mode it swtiches back to the 3D view focal lens, which is 50mm in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has to do with the default focal lens of an object that is chosen as camera. As Lemon says, you've chosen *Sprinkle_medium* as camera instead of your camera, as you can see in the *Scene* panel. It looks like the focal is 35mm for an object camera, and when you switch back to *Solid* mode, instead of keeping this focal as it would do with a real camera, it swtiches back to the 3D view focal lens, which is 50mm in your case, therefore the difference you see. If what I say is correct, I think there's a lack of consistency here (but objects as camera are not often used I suppose).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I haven't even visited Scene panel yet) I've probably used some wrong shortcuts. I looked around and found all you explained except the focal lens of the object. When I click on the Sprinkle_medium object, the camera tab disappears at all. Just wondering where to find it's parameters.

Comment: is it the size parameter under Camera tab? It's 36 here, not 35mm so I'm not sure: https://tppr.me/YXk7P

Comment: What you show is your camera tab for the camera, isn't it? Because I can't find a way to set the focal lens for an object chosen as camera...

Comment: Yes) I also couldn't find that's why I asked how did you find out that "focal is 35mm for an object camera". But I'm just wondering, it's not super important

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's exactly 35mm, I'v just set my 3D view to 35mm in the N panel > View > Focal Length, and compared with the Rendered preview with the object selected as camera, and it seems to match (or about to match)

Comment: Wow, okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for clearing it up!